# pyinstaller exe created on Windows 10 does not work in Windows 7, cublasLt64_11.dll missing

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, cupy

I created a exe with pyinstaller on my windows 10 machine. I am using python 3.8.5, cupy-cuda102, and CUDA 10.2. I also installed visual studio 2015. The exe runs fine on my machine. When running the exe on a customer's windows 7 machine, it has error: "The program can't start because cublasLt64_11.dll is missing from your computer". The target windows 7 machine also installed CUDA 10.2.

I am confused about the error why it is looking for cublasLt64_11.dll (which should belong to CUDA 11). We did install CUDA 11.4 on my windows 10 and the windows 7 machine before but later found out it is not supported by windows 7 so I uninstalled CUDA 11.4 and reinstalled 10.2 on both machines.

I cannot access the customer's windows 7 machine directly and I can only work on my windows 10 machine to create the exe. Any suggestions how to debug/solve this issue?

Comment: You probably need to use dependency walker or something similar to diagnose what dlls the executable you built requires. And then try and understand how/why  pyinstaller has added them to the dependency list for the build

Comment: @talonmies Thank you. I was able to find it out through dependency walker.

Answer (score 0):

An EXE built on Windows 10 is often not backwards compatible with Windows 7.

This has worked for me in the past: Build the EXE on Windows 7, then run the EXE on Windows 7 and 10. This is not a sure thing, so you might have to make the EXE on Windows 10 and run the EXE only on Windows 10.